# Int doesn't reach 11 in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a nihoshim UILabel that his last character is 0, and I want to update it by one everyTime the else statement is true and called, everything works fine until it get to 10 and then it suddenly equal 1,

```
 guard var yoo = Int(nihoshim.text!.suffix(1)) else {
        return
    }
    var alephbet = ["א","ב","ג","ד","ה","ו","ז","ח","ט","י","כ","ל","מ","נ","ס","ע","פ","צ","ק","ר","ש","ת"]
    nihoshim.text! = "ניחושים: " + String(yoo)
    if gameLabel.text!.count <= 3 && (sender.tag == 18 || sender.tag == 20) {
        gameLabel.text = gameLabel.text! + alephbet[alpha.index(after: tag) - 1]
        sender.isHidden = true
    } else if sender.tag == 10 && !(gameLabel.text?.contains("יי"))!{

        sender.isHidden = false
        gameLabel.text = gameLabel.text! + alephbet[alpha.index(after: tag) - 1]
    }
    else {
        yoo += 1
        nihoshim.text! = "ניחושים: " + String(yoo)
        sender.isHidden = true
        print(yoo)
    }
```

When I print it, even the value of yoo is changing to 0 without any reason. and when I updated it to `yoo += 20` I click on it a few times and its still 20 and one more click it goes to 1.

Comment: Your `guard` has two `else` statements, can you update your code to make it valid Swift code?

Comment: @user28434 look at the update, It wasn't the whole code

Comment: What is inside `nihoshim.text!` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are only checking the last character, you need to get the whole number at the end of your string, for example with:

```
let numberString = nihoshim.text!.split(separator: " ").last ?? nihoshim.text!.suffix(0)
```

In your code it would look like this:

```
let numberString = nihoshim.text!.split(separator: " ").last ?? nihoshim.text!.suffix(0)
guard var yoo = Int(numberString) else {
    return
}
var alephbet = ["א","ב","ג","ד","ה","ו","ז","ח","ט","י","כ","ל","מ","נ","ס","ע","פ","צ","ק","ר","ש","ת"]
nihoshim.text! = "ניחושים: " + String(yoo)
if gameLabel.text!.count <= 3 && (sender.tag == 18 || sender.tag == 20) {
    gameLabel.text = gameLabel.text! + alephbet[alpha.index(after: tag) - 1]
    sender.isHidden = true
} else if sender.tag == 10 && !(gameLabel.text?.contains("יי"))!{

    sender.isHidden = false
    gameLabel.text = gameLabel.text! + alephbet[alpha.index(after: tag) - 1]
}
else {
    yoo += 1
    nihoshim.text! = "ניחושים: " + String(yoo)
    sender.isHidden = true
    print(yoo)
}
```